# Treenode to GridView

Tags: extjs4, draggable, drag, treenode, gridpanel

ExtJS4

I'm trying to move a treenode to gridpanel. I want its associated data to be inserted here. But whenever I move the treenode, it creates an empty row at that position.
I've created the tree as:

```
    var treeData = {
        text: 'Business Processes',
        children:[
            {text: 'Process7', lob: 'Lob7', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process8', lob: 'Lob8', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process9', lob: 'Lob9', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process10', lob: 'Lob10', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process11', lob: 'Lob11', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process12', lob: 'Lob12', leaf:true}
        ]
    };
    bpTreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{});
    bpTreeStore.setRootNode(treeData);

    new Ext.TreePanel({
        id:'businessProcessTree',
        store : bpTreeStore,
        viewConfig: {
            plugins:{
                ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
                dropGroup: 'dragGroup',
                dragGroup: 'dragGroup',
                dragText: 'Place the node to grid'
              }
        }
    });
```

And the grid as

```
Ext.define('BusinessProcessStoreModel',{
extend:'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
{ name:'businessProcessName', type:'string' },
{ name:'businessProcessLob', type:'string' }
]
});
bpMappingStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        model:'BusinessProcessStoreModel',
        data:[
            ['Process1', 'Lob1'],
            ['Process2', 'Lob2'],
            ['Process3', 'Lob3']
        ]
    });
var bpMappingGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
        id:'bpGridPanel',
        region:'center',
        frame:true,
        layout:'fit',
        height:300,
        columns:[
        { header:'Process Name', dataIndex:'businessProcessName' },
        { header:'Process Lob', dataIndex:'businessProcessLob' }
        ],
        store:bpMappingStore,
        viewConfig: {
            plugins:{
                ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                dropGroup: 'dragGroup',
                dragGroup: 'dragGroup',
                dragText: 'Place the node to grid'
              },
            listeners: {
                drop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition)
                {
                    var position = (dropPosition=='after'?overModel.index + 1: overModel.index -1);
                    Ext.getCmp('bpGridPanel').store.insert(position, [[data.records[0].data.text, 'LOB']]);
 //data.records[0].data.lob is undefined don't know why

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Please tell me how I refer to the 'text' and 'lob' of the treenode to be inserted into the two columns of the gridpanel.

Here I've created my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Make sure that the Treenode being dragged must contain the attributes in the model which the grid is using.

Here, treedata can be defined as

```
var treeData = {
        text: 'Business Processes',
        children:[
            {text: 'Process7', businessProcessName: 'Process7', businessProcessLob: 'Lob7', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process8', businessProcessName: 'Process8', businessProcessLob: 'Lob8', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process9', businessProcessName: 'Process9', businessProcessLob: 'Lob9', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process10',businessProcessName: 'Process10', businessProcessLob: 'Lob10', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process11', businessProcessName: 'Process11', businessProcessLob: 'Lob11', leaf:true},
            {text: 'Process12', businessProcessName: 'Process12', businessProcessLob: 'Lob12', leaf:true}
        ]
    };
    this.bpTreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{root: this.treeData});
```

But when we assign this treedata object to the treestore. It removes the new attributes (businessProcessName and businessProcessLob).

So to add them, a loop can be run.

```
for(var index in treeData.children)
{
    this.bpTreeStore.tree.root.childNodes[index].data.businessProcessName = treeData.children[index].businessProcessName;
    this.bpTreeStore.tree.root.childNodes[index].data.businessProcessLob = treeData.children[index].businessProcessLob;
}
```

After this, dragging works fine :)